# How do I feed my keras model in batches?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to feed a Sequential model in batches. To be reproducible my example, suppose my data is:

```
X=np.random.rand(24,432)
Y=np.random.rand(24,432)
```

**My goal is to feed the model in batches. 24 points at a time (24 x 1 vector), 432 times.**

---

I built my model as:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=12)

model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,)),
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
      keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
  ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])



#train_generator = batch_generator(X_train, y_train, 12)
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=12, validation_split=0.3)

early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=100)
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=20)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Model loss:',test_loss, 'Model accuracy: ',test_acc)
```

However, I get this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='flatten_24_input'), name='flatten_24_input', description="created by layer 'flatten_24_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 432)
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
X=np.array(X[0:10368]).reshape(24,432)
Y=np.array(Y[0:10368]).reshape(24,432)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=12)

model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Flatten(batch_input_shape=(None, 432, 2)),
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),

      keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
  ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.3)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Model loss:',test_loss, 'Model accuracy: ',test_acc)
```

NOW RAISES:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_17 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 864 but received input with shape (None, 432)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that your labels - **Y** values you initialize randomly at the beginning is 432 dimensional, while your final layer is 2 dimensional and you are using binary cross-entropy. Which means you are trying to predict a 432 dimensional vector as a binary classification.

But that is not reason you are receiving an error message for. To fix the error, you can use `batch_input_shape(None, 432, 1)` instead of `input_shape(1, )`. Once you fix this, you will get a value error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 432))
```

Which in turn fixed in the way describe above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and your explanation. After fixing what you said, a new value error is raised relative to the shape of my data again. See the EDIT above please.